# Pairwise recommender system

Tags: feature-selection, recommender-system

How can I model the following situation? I am looking for high level recommendations.

if say a man with certain attributes (income, age, etc ...) rates a car with a given attributes (color, horsepower, type). How can this situation be modeled in ML if I were to predict the ratings for each pair of customer and car?

Recommender systems either look at the historical data of the customer (content-based) or compare to other customers (filtering). Do you know of any system that **necessarily** takes the features of the pair for making a recommendation?